# How to add change class on body for different pages in nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

I'm using Mozilla Nunjucks templating system for a static website which has multiple pages. For some purpose, I want to add a class to `body` tag for each different page

About us page > `<body class="about">`

Home > `<body class="home">`

I can do this very easily if `body` tag I keep inside every page but I want to keep `body` tag inside my template which I would be using for all pages.

I want to change classes conditionally.

Comment: How do you render the templates? Can you pass page-specific variables to the renderer?

Comment: @xmojmr - I'm using gulp-nunjucks-html plugin

Comment: Can you pass page-specific (`body class`) variable to https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nunjucks-html#options-locals ?

Comment: @xmojmr I would like to achieve this without editing my gulp file

Comment: @xmojmr ok if even I'm ok with adding variable i don't know how to do that. this is my gulp task https://gist.github.com/jitendravyas/31a22db17f9868506126

Comment: The scenario I had on my mind would expect something like `<body class="{{ body_class }}">` in the master template and page-specific `body_class` variables. The master template could do whatever `if` logic is needed

Answer (score 6):

1. Set variable on your page. On your page.njk:
   `{% set bodyClass = "pageClass" %}`
2. Call bodyClass on layout. `<body{% if bodyClass %} class="{{ bodyClass }}"{% endif %}>`

Answer (score 3):

It's not fully dynamic, but you can set variables inside your page templates and use those in a conditional to set the body class.

**layout.nunjucks**

```
{% if pgHome %}
  <body class="home">
{% elif pgAbout %}
  <body class="about">
{% else %}
  <body class="page">
{% endif %}
```

**home.nunjucks**

```
{% extends "layout.nunjucks" %}
{% set pgHome = true %}


  Homepage Markup
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Layout:

```html
<body class="{%block bodyClass %}{% endblock %}">
```

Page:

```html
{% block bodyClass %} about {% endblock %}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it also render the page name on the page

Comment: What do you mean by it renders the page name on the page

Comment: I believe what he'd want to do is if the page being compiled is "about.html" you can some how access the name of the file "about" and use that name within the template so you don't have to explicitly set the page class. This would allow someone to make arbitrary page names and count on the class being set from the file-name and not have to repeat oneself.